# How to check for special characters inside of a password using javascript

Tags: javascript

My code is setup to check for special characters inside of a given password. The program is suppose to store true to a variable if a special character was found, and false if one was not found; Afterwards, it will print the result of the variable. The problem is the program keeps printing out false even when there's a special character inside of the password. I don't know what's wrong

```js
const arrayOfSp = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*", "_", "-", "?"];
const password = "Patrick_";
let specialCharacterCheck = false;

const special = (c) => {
  for (i = 0; i < arrayOfSp.length; i++) {
    if (c === arrayOfSp[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

for (i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
  if (special(password[i])) {
    specialCharacterCheck = true;
  }
}
console.log(specialCharacterCheck);
```

Comment: You need to use `let` variable before each `i` variable in loop.

Comment: this is unrelated to your direct question, but I would highly recommend use of .includes() to save time instead of iterating over every character of your string being checked

Answer (score 1):

You need to break from the loop as soon as it finds a special character. To find special character in the array you can use `find` which will return `undefined` is no matching character is found

```js
const arrayOfSp = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*", "_", "-", "?"];
const password = "Patr_ick";
let specialCharacterCheck = false;

const special = (c) => {
  return arrayOfSp.find(item => item === c)
}

for (let i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
  const isPresent = special(password[i]);
  if (isPresent) {
    specialCharacterCheck = true;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(specialCharacterCheck);
```

Comment: For type compatibility, you can use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `.find` on the array in `special`.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) here

```js
const arrayOfSp = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*", "_", "-", "?"];
const password = "Patrick_";

const specialChars = new Set(arrayOfSp);
let specialCharacterCheck = [...password].some((c) => specialChars.has(c));

console.log(specialCharacterCheck);
```

Comment: `split`ting a string will not handle utf-8 surrogate pairs correctly, and this won't work anyway if there's a special larger than 2 bytes. Using `[...password].some(/* ... */)` is better (but still won't handle the surrogate pairs (e.g. ‍♀️).

Comment: @jsejcksn That's a fine piece of advice. Thanks updated. `brain.set(useSpreadForSurrogatePairs)` 

Answer (score 1):

I like using a regex approach here:

```js
var arrayOfSp = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*", "_", "?", "-"];
var password = "Patrick_";
var regex = "[" + arrayOfSp.join("") + "]";
if (new RegExp(regex).test(password)) {
    console.log("Password is valid");
}
else {
    console.log("Password is invalid");
}
```

Note that I have deliberately placed `-` at the end of your input array, to avoid including an unwanted range of characters in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a functional approach:

```js
const arrayOfSp = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*", "_", "-", "?"];
const password = "Patrick_";

function hasSpecial (specials, password) {
  for (const str of specials) {
    if (!password.includes(str)) continue;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(hasSpecial(arrayOfSp, password));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `String.prototype.includes()` to check if the string contains any specific character or string.

```js
function doesContainSpecial(string) {
  const specialChars = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*", "_", "-", "?"];
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string.includes(specialChars[i])) return true;
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(doesContainSpecial("Patri_ck")); // Expected Output: True
console.log(doesContainSpecial("Patrick")); // Expected Output: False
```

You can read more about `String.prototype.includes()` at [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

You can also use Regular Expression To Do The Same Task:

```js
function doesContainSpecial(string) {
  var specialChars = "[!@#$%&*_?-]" // Put all your Special Characters Between Square Brackets
  var regex = new RegExp(specialChars)
  return regex.test(string)
}

console.log(doesContainSpecial("Patri_ck")); // Expected Output: True
console.log(doesContainSpecial("Patrick")); // Expected Output: False
```

Using Regex is much more efficient than using `.includes()`

You can read more about `Regular Expressions` at [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is:

```
[...password].some((e) => arrayOfSp.includes(e))
```

But if you need validate object (including password) may be it worth to use a special tool for validation like [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup).